# How to utilize the Django URL tag?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry for such a beginner question but I have a TemplateSyntaxError on my URL line in my HTML that links to the HTML that allows user to update the article details and I cannot seem to debug it.

Below is article_detail.html where it would have a link to article_update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Title: {{object.title}}</h3>

<p>Caption: {{object.caption}}</p>
<p>Activeness: {{object.active}}</p>

<a href="{% url 'articleupdate' id:article_id %}">Update this Article</a>

{% endblock %}
```

In the views.py, I have created an article_update_view function as seen below

```
def article_update_view(request, article_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ArticleForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'article_update.html', context)
```

and in my app.urls.py, I have written

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:article_id>/update/', article_update_view, name='articleupdate'),
]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have another view which renders this `article_update.html` template, don't you? If so, can you update your question with that view and template, please?

Comment: @Higor Rossato I have a weak understanding of Django currently but I think I only have one view that renders this article_update.html. I am simply creating a URL link from article_detail.html to article_update.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the way you're passing the `object id`.

**template.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Title: {{object.title}}</h3>

<p>Caption: {{object.caption}}</p>
<p>Activeness: {{object.active}}</p>

<a href="{% url 'articleupdate' object.id %}">Update this Article</a> # or object.article_id

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Oh, well that was a silly mistake but thank you so much for solving the problem. I have a better understanding of the framework now. Appreciate it! @Higor Rossato